A better phrase for "vast minority"
I've occasionally used the phrase "vast minority" (as the opposite of "vast majority"), essentially meaning "a very small part of the whole". For instance:

Even though my views regarding this are not particularly radical by US standards, in my country I'm still in the vast minority on this issue.

This uses "vast" as an amplifier of the "minority" part. However, the phrase feels a bit oxymoronic to me, or at least could easily be misunderstood as "something that's in the minority but is still very large". Is there a better, less ambiguous phrase that can be used in the same contexts?

By decreasing order : large -> significant -> small -> tiny -> infinitesimal  minority

Related: Is "vast majority" something to avoid? The converse could be tiny minority.

The opposite "emphatic" designation is a tiny minority.

vast minority is pretty much a no-go

https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2020/09/vast-minority.html

Your intuition is correct. Vast means large, broad, expansive, and so on. It's not a good qualifier to describe the smallness of something.
I would say something like:

My views would not be considered radical by US standards but in my country, they're shared by only a fringe minority.


"fringe" often has a negative connotation.

Fair point. You could just use small minority, narrow minority, etc.

Oh, I like narrow minority, guess that'll work.

an insignificant minority

"narrow minority" sounds too close to "narrow loss" for me, and it may not be immediately obvious that it indicates a very small amount rather than a narrow loss; in my opinion, you're better just to use tiny/minuscule/insignificant/negligible/wee/etc.

I guess either of two should work:

Minor segment
Limited few

